# Count Criteria joining columns

Tags: jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I'm trying to count the rows of the filter the user uses, when the user wants to list all it works fine, the problem is when they use filters and that makes some joins to work properly.

(This is used for a lazy datatable in jsf)

My criteria code is:

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<CarreraHorizontal> cq = cb.createQuery(CarreraHorizontal.class);
        Root<CarreraHorizontal> root = cq.from(CarreraHorizontal.class);
        CriteriaQuery<Long> cqCount = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        Join<CarreraHorizontal, Gdp> childJoin = root.join("gdp", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<CarreraHorizontal, Empleado> childJoin2 = root.join("empleado", JoinType.LEFT);

        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(grupoTitulacion))
            predicates.add(cb.like(root.<String>get("grupoTitulacion"), "%" + grupoTitulacion + "%"));

        if(gdp0Bool) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(childJoin.<String>get("nombre"), "GDP0"));
            if(!StringUtils.isBlank(gdp0Combo))
                predicates.add(cb.le(childJoin.<Integer>get("numEscalones"), Integer.parseInt(gdp0Combo)));
        }

        if(epg6) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(childJoin2.get("progresionEscalon"), epg6));
        }   
        //cq.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
        cqCount.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

        Root<CarreraHorizontal> rootCount = cqCount.from(CarreraHorizontal.class);

        CriteriaQuery<Long> a = cqCount.select(cb.count(rootCount));
        TypedQuery<Long> res = em.createQuery(a.select(cb.count(rootCount)));

        return res.getSingleResult();
```

My exception is:

Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.progresionEscalon' [select count(generatedAlias0) from es.valencia.gp.sbch.entity.CarreraHorizontal as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias1.progresionEscalon=:param0]

I tried everything I found but it's still not working.

Comment: Can you remove the joins and check if it works, then adding one at a time, you can see which join fails. Then, show or check the correctness of the join relationships in the entity definitions

Comment: When I use just the root one, it works, when i start adding joins, neither works.